# How to include 1st, 2nd, 3rd instead of writing it out

Tags: python

```html
   
# extension
modify = input("Would you like to modify your recordings? Yes or No?  ")
if modify == ("Yes","yes","Y","y"):
    print ("OK")
if modify == ("No","no","n","N"):
    print ("You may now exit the program")


print("")
name = input ("Whose score would you like to modify? Type it in with this format -  Name, Age Category:  ")    
if name == ("Jane, Under 11"):
           answer = input ("Would you like to add or delete data? ")
if name == ("Grant, Under 11"):
           answer = input ("Would you like to add or delete data? ")
if name == ("Lilly, Under 11"):
           answer = input ("Would you like to add or delete data? ")
if name == ("Henry, Over 11"):
           answer = input ("Would you like to add or delete data? ")
if name == ("Jane, Over 11"):
           answer = input ("Would you like to add or delete data? ")
if name == ("Naomi, Over 11"):
           answer = input ("Would you like to add or delete data? ")                                
if answer == ("add" ,"Add"):
    pos = input ("Type in the position(s) you would like to add: ")
elif answer == ("delete" ,"Delete", "del", "Del"):
    delete = input ("Would you like to delete position or name?")
if delete == ("pos","Pos","Position","position"):
    print ("Position deleted. Here is the final outcome: ",name)
elif delete == ("Name", "name"):
    print ("Name deleted. There is no data now")

if pos == ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', '9th', '10th','11th', '12th', '13th', '14th', '15th', '16th', '17th', '18th', '19th', '20th', '21st', '22nd', '23rd', '24th', '25th', '26th', '27th', '28th', '29th', '30th', '31st'):
    print ("Posititon added. Here is their final score: ", name, " ", pos)
```

Hello. I am new to SO so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this however I am trying to answer a question where I am told to use pickle and store data inside a file. I am also told that the code should be able to let the user select a list to delete, be able to change a player position(its about a tennis competition) and be able to store the position of players in their last three tournaments. I need to do it in certain age categories

Everything works well so far however I need to do the positions as 1st 2nd 3rd and so on up to 1000. I have started writing it out(see penultimate line) but it would take extremely long to write it out so does anyone know a way to save time and solve this problem??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Remove the redundant code (most of this is unrelated to the error) and include the entire error message (with trace-back).

Comment: There are a number of problems with this input sequence: you've written a *lot* of code without testing the individual blocks.  Look up how to check a variable against multiple values, how to input and compare a string, and how to identify if a string is any of a variety of choices.  There are many on-line sources and tutorials to cover these techniques.

Comment: Also practice incremental programming: write *one, tiny* bit of code, maybe 1-3 lines, and test it before you go on.  You've tried to write the entire program, apparently without testing the blocks.  You now face having to identify and repair at least three problems before you can get any meaningful progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd little program, which will break if you don't enter answers with exactly what you're expected to enter.

I was able to get your error when I typed "No" (accidentally) after the prompt "Whose score would you like to modify?"

Since you haven't instantiated the variable `answer` before your `if` statements (as @Enes pointed out) and since none of your `if` statements are true, I didn't have anything stored in the `answer` variable, when you called

```
if answer == ("add" ,"Add"):...
```

this threw an error.

So if you fix the error that @Schlator mentioned
(Change

```
if modify == ("Yes","yes","Y","y"):
```

to

```
if modify in ("Yes","yes","Y","y"):
```

everywhere)
and if you instantiate your variable `answer` as Enes mentioned
(Add

```
answer = ""
```

before

```
name = input ("Whose score would you like to modify? Type it in with this format - Name, Age Category: ")
```

)
then at least your fragile little program will exit gracefully.

Comment: Thank you GuyStalks the code has improved however when running and the user gets to the question of whether they would like to add or delete data, the error message still appears.

Comment: Is the error the same? Or is the error now:

    ```NameError: name 'delete' is not defined```

If it's the latter, you can fix this error by instantiating the ```delete``` variable just as with the ```answer``` variable.

Comment: (you have the same problem with the variable ```pos```)

Comment: Thanks for choosing me for the correct answer! It's my first one on StackOverflow! Whee!

Comment: Hey Cookie, it seems that you edited your question significantly. It would be better to create a new question (after following Prune’s suggestions). I doubt anyone else will reply to this question now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are mistaken with the syntax

It **shouldn't** be

```
if modify == ("Yes","yes","Y","y"):
```

rather it **should** be

```
if modify in ("Yes","yes","Y","y"):
```

Similarly for other if conditions that you have used in other parts of the program.

Comment: Thank you Schlator, although this makes much more sense in the code, it still doesn't make a difference of the NameError...

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your program, you will *always* drop through to `if answer ==` with `answer` being undefined.  Your input and test sequence:

```
name = input ("Whose score would you like to modify? Type it in with this format -  Name, Age Category:  ")    
if name == ("Jane, Under 11"):
```

cannot possibly match the choices you've given, because every input will contain a newline.  You need to either include that in your test, or `strip` it from the input before checking.